# An uncountable Product of $\Bbb R$ with itself(box topology) is not metrizable

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

How can I prove that an uncountable product of $\Bbb R$ with itself in the box topology is not metrizable? In munkres pp 130-131(section 21, example 1 and 2) it shows that $\Bbb R^{\omega}$ in the box topology and an uncountable product of $\Bbb R$ with itself in the product topology are not metrizable, but doesn't say anything about the uncountable box case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I$ be an uncountable set, let $X_i=\Bbb R$ with the usual topology for each $i\in I$, and let $X=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ with the box topology. Let $I_0$ be a countably infinite subset of $I$, let

$$Y_i=\begin{cases}
X_i,&\text{if }i\in I_0\\
\{0\},&\text{if }i\in I\setminus I_0\,.
\end{cases}$$

and let $Y=\prod_{i\in I}Y_i$. Then $Y$ with the subspace topology that it inherits from $X$ is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^\omega$ with the box topology. If $X$ were metrizable, every subspace of it would be metrizable. $Y$ isn’t metrizable, so $X$ cannot be metrizable either.